# How to disable Date() Method in VBScript temporarily to retrieve Object Child Property with the same name?

Tags: vb.net, methods, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

When I try to create a dictionary object using a list of appointments from a window I need to pull the date of the appointments.  When I go to use the apptList.Item(i).Date is is trying to convert it to a date rather than pull the information from the object property with the same name.  How do I disable the Date() method temporarily to retrieve the actual information and not use the method?

```
Set apptList = WpfWindow("...").WpfList("...").Object.Items

Set canceledApptList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i  = 0 To apptList.Count - 1

    If apptList.Item(i).StatusDescription = "Canceled" Then
        canceledApptList.Add (i+1), apptList.Item(i).ReasonDescription, apptList.Item(i).Date,apptList.Item(i).StatusDescription
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is this code running via vbscript or vb.net?  Does it help if you add parentheses to `apptList.Item(i).Date()` ?

Comment: I am using UFT to identify the .NET properties of the object and within UFT I am trying to pull the Date text using VBScript

Answer (score 0):

There is no .Add method in/for Scripting.Dictionary objects. So

```
canceledApptList.Add (i+1), apptList.Item(i).ReasonDescription, apptList.Item(i).Date,apptList.Item(i).StatusDescription
```

throws an runtime error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'Add'

Plain VBScript has no problems with 'ambigous' member names:

```
Option Explicit

Class cMagic
  Public Property Get Date
    Date = "not a date"
  End Property
End Class

WScript.Echo Date
Dim oMagic : Set oMagic = New cMagic
WScript.Echo oMagic.Date

Dim d : Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "Key", "Value"
WScript.Echo "Key", d("Key")
d.Add "Key1", "Value1", "Value2"
```

output:

```
cscript 27551253.vbs
18.12.2014
not a date
Key Value
... runtime error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'Add'
```

**Update wrt comments:**

I'd try to check my assumption step by step, using code something like this:

```
Set a = WpfWindow("...")
WScript.Echo 0, VarType(a), TypeName(a)
Set b = a.WpfList("...")
WScript.Echo 1, VarType(b), TypeName(b)
Set c = b.Object
WScript.Echo 2, VarType(c), TypeName(c)
Set d = c.Items
WScript.Echo 3, VarType(d), TypeName(d)
Set e = d.Item(0)
WScript.Echo 4, VarType(e), TypeName(e)
[Set] f = e.Date
WScript.Echo 5, VarType(f), TypeName(f)
```

Again: `Date()` is a native function. An expression like x.Date will either throw an "Object doesn't support this property or method" or access the Date member of x, but never call the native function.

**Update wrt to "the next msgbox is giving me a blank empty box":**

To me, this evidence indicates that

(1) `WpfWindow("...").WpfList("...").Object.Items.Item(0).Date` is (in some general sense) empty. Check

```
VarType(WpfWindow("...").WpfList("...").Object.Items.Item(0).Date)
TypeName(WpfWindow("...").WpfList("...").Object.Items.Item(0).Date)
```

(2) The native function isn't involved at all.

Comment: Thank You, I did not know I could override methods using a Class.

Comment: But now when I try to us Date = WpfWindow("...").WpfList("...").Object.Items.Item(0).Date it is trying to convert it before setting Date() to the Object's member.

Comment: In **VBScript** trying to do `Date = <whatever>` throws "Illegal Assingment". Do you use "On Error Resume Next"?

Comment: Class cMagic
   Public Property Get Date
     Date = WpfWindow("...").WpfList("...").Object.Items.Item(0).Date
   End Property
 End Class
 
 Msgbox Date
 Set apptList = New cMagic
 msgbox apptList.Date

Comment: What is displayed in the MsgBoxes? What is your evidence for 'trying to **convert** it'? `Date` returns the current date, it doesn't convert anything.

Comment: The first msgbox displays the current date and then the next msgbox is giving me a blank empty box.

Comment: using this for the other two apptList.Item(i).ReasonDescription & apptList.Item(i).StatusDescription both work.